# Is this function Schwartz?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, elliptic-pde, fourier-transform, schrodinger-operators

I already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397339/another-equivalent-characterization-of-schwartz-function) on MSE, didn't get an answer, and I'm still stuck with it.

---

Suppose I have a smooth function $\psi$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$, for which I know that 
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\left||x|^k\Delta^{p}\psi(x)\right|<\infty
$$
for all $k,p\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Is this already sufficient for $\psi$ to be a Schwartz function?

---

I have tried fooling around with the Fourier transform, the problem seems to be however, that I am not able to control terms of the form
$$
|x|D^p(|x|^{2k}\hat{\psi})
$$In particular, it doesn't seem to be possible to adapt the proof, that the Fourier transform is an isomorphism of Schwartz spaces, or I'm just too dumb to see it. I also tried to apply a vast number of different inequalities, but I didn't find anything that fits my problem. I didn't find a counterexample either.

Background: I have a Schrödinger resolvent, i.e. a solution $\psi$ of the equation
$$
(-\Delta+V-\lambda)\psi=\varphi
$$
where $-\Delta+V$ is e.s.a. on an appropiate kernel, $\varphi$ is Schwartz and $V$ is $C^\infty$ and slowly growing. Using semigroup estimates, I managed to prove that $\psi$ is polynomially bounded, rearranging the equation gives me that $\Delta\psi$ is polynomially bounded.

Any help in form of proofs, proof ideas or possible counterexamples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For Schwartz, I also need polynomial boundedness in all derivatives.

Comment: Right, I was asleep.

Comment: Essentially, this is about controlling $\nabla\psi$ in terms of $\psi,\Delta\psi$ so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood.E2.80.93Sobolev_lemma and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_transform should be useful.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you for your suggestion! I actually tried some Sobolev-Type inequalities, but so far I didn't stumble over the Riez transform. The problem with the Sobolev-Type inequalities was usually, that I pay too much when passing to the sup. Riez transform looks useful in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bound is sufficient to prove that $u$ is a Schwartz function.

Your assumption implies that $x^\alpha \Delta^p u$ is in $L^2$ for all $\alpha,k$. Thus for the Fourier transform $v$ of $u$ we have that $D^\alpha(|x|^{2p}v)$ is in $L^2$ for all $\alpha,p$. Take $\alpha=0$: we get that $|x|^{2p}v$ is in $L^2$ for all $p$. Now take $\alpha=(1,0,...,0)$: we have $|x|^{2p}\partial_1v+2p|x|^{2p-2}x_1v$ is in $L^2$ for all $p$, which by the previous step implies $|x|^{2p}\partial_1v$ is in $L^2$ for all $p$. And so on. Finally you get that $|x|^{2p}D^\alpha v$ is in $L^2$ for all $\alpha,p$ thus $v$ is Schwartz.

Comment: Why is $x_1|x|^{2p-2}v$ polynomially bounded?

Comment: I meant bounded, sorry

Comment: It is bounded by $(|x|^{2p}+|x|^{2p-2})|v|$ which is in $L^2$. What is your doubt?

Comment: Hm, I actually didn't write what I meant, and I am not sure anymore whether what I meant is right :D I'll check as soon as I am home.

Comment: Yeah, sadly what I actually meant seems to be right. I already tried something like this, the problem here is the "and so on"-part - in the induction step, I will get terms like $\partial_i|x|^{2p}D^\alpha v$ or similar (In my original attempt, I got the $|x|D^\alpha|x|^{2p} v$ from the question, as I came from the other side), and I have not figured out how to control them.

Comment: The 'and so on' step is trivial. The top term has all derivative on $v$, the other terms have lower order derivatives so they have been estimated in the previous step. But I think I explained enough, so if you are not convinced that's fine with me

Comment: Oh my god, I am totally stupid and you are totally right. Sorry.